# Jenkins pipeline - Environment variable for docker-compose

Tags: docker, jenkins, docker-compose, jenkins-pipeline

I'm trying to use `docker-compose` with environment variable for the image name set by the `Jenkinsfile` but it is not working.

I have a `Jenkinsfile` containing

```groovy
node() {

  stage('Checkout') {
    cleanWs()
    git credentialsId: 'xxx', url: 'ssh://git@...'
  }

  stage('Build') {
    withMaven(maven: 'maven-3.5.3') {
      sh 'mvn clean package'
      def pom = readMavenPom file:'pom.xml'
      JAR_FILE = pom.artifactId + "-" + pom.version + ".jar"
      JAR_VERSION = pom.version
    }
  }

  stage('Build Docker Image') {
    echo "Docker Build ..."
    docker.withTool('docker') {
      app = docker.build("microservices/my-service:${JAR_VERSION}","--build-arg JAR_FILE=${JAR_FILE} .")
    }
  }

  stage('Running Docker Container') {
    echo "Docker Run ..."
    withEnv(['VERSION=1.0.0']) {
      docker.withTool('docker') {
        sh "docker-compose rm -f -s -v"
        sh "docker-compose up -d"
      }
    }
    cleanWs()
  }
}
```

And a `docker-compose.yml` like

```yaml
version: '3.6'

services:

    my-service:
        image: microservices/my-service:${VERSION}
        container_name: my-service
        ...
```

Everything is working fine excepts that the last stage is not using my environment variable.

```
Docker Run ...
[Pipeline] withEnv
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] tool

[Pipeline] withEnv
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] sh

[my-service] Running shell script
+ docker-compose rm -f -s -v
The VERSION variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
```

Answer (score 4):

After adding a `sh "printenv"` juste before the `sh "docker-compose ..."` I saw

```
Version=1.0.0
```

I don't know why `withEnv(['VERSION=1.0.0'])` give me `Version=1.0.0` but using, in the `docker-compose-yml` `image: microservices/my-service:${Version}` in place of `image: microservices/my-service:${VERSION}` works fine.

Comment: That is very strange behavior - what if you use a different key like `MY_SPECIFIC_VERSION=1.0.0`? I'm wondering if there is already some inherited `Version` environment variable key from the build agent or something.

Answer (score 3):

You need to save these ENV in a file (output of jenkinsfile, input of dockercompose file).
Then, you have two possibilities:

1. If you need your ENV inside `my-service` container save your ENV in `./your_envfile.env`, and just add

   ```
   version: '3.6'
   services:
       my-service:
           image: microservices/my-service:${VERSION}
           container_name: my-service
           env_file: ./your_envfile.env
   ```
2. If you need to use your ENV in docker-compose file, as I see in your `image` section with `${VERSION}`, you need to save your ENV in `.env` file.

`.env` file must be in the same path that you execute docker-compose, or at least a symlink named `./env` which points somewhere you've saved ENV in this format:

`VERSION=1.0.0 
...`

Comment: Thnaks for your solution.  Did not tried because I found another way.

Comment: Could you share which way ? :)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to put the following `environment` in your Jenkinsfile?

```
{
    ...
    stage('Running Docker Container') {
        echo "Docker Run ..."
        docker.withTool('docker') {
            sh "docker-compose rm -f -s -v"
            sh "docker-compose up -d"
        }
        cleanWs()
    }

    environment {
        VERSION = "1.0.0"
    }
}
```

Additionnaly, you can use default values using a `.env` file but @mulg0r ([permalink](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51513721/3756843)) is explaining this solution in his answer. You can read the [variable substitution in docker-compose documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#variable-substitution) for further information.